# Calculating the normal of a point on a heightfield

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have a spherical heightfield, defined by a function `f(x, y, z)` which returns the distance from the origin of the surface of the heightfield of a line which passes from the origin through `(x,y,z)`.

(In other words, the isosurface for my heightfield is `|x,y,z| = f(x,y,z)`.)

(Also, for the sake of discussion below, I'm going to assume that `surface(x,y,z)` is the location of the point on the surface directly below `(x,y,z)`.)

When rendering this, I need to calculate the normal for any point on the heightfield. What's the cheapest way of doing this?

To calculate the normal of a point on a rectangular heightfield, the usual trick is to offset `(x,y,z)` slightly in two directions parallel to the nominal surface, calculate three points on the heightfield to form a triangle, and then use the cross product to calculate the triangle's normal. This is easy as the three points can simply be `surface(x,y,z)`, `surface(x+1,y,z)` and `surface(x,y+1,z)` (or similar). But for a spherical heightfield it's a little trickier because the normal can point in any direction. Simply displacing by `x` and `y` won't do because if two of my points fall on a radius, then `surface()` of them will return the same location and I won't get a triangle.

In the past what I've done is to use the vector `<x,y,z>` as a radius from the sphere's origin; then calculate a vector perpendicular to it; then rotate this vector around `<x,y,z>` to give me my three points. But this is fiddly and expensive and shouldn't be necessary. There must be a cheaper way. What is it?

Comment: Can you isolate the cases where the "trick" won't work, so that you only need to use the expensive technique in those cases?  This assumes, of course, that 1) determining when the trick fails is cheap and 2) the trick works most of the time.

Comment: I'll only have problems when a radius of my sphere coincides with the X, Y or Z axis (assuming I'm displacing in those directions). I could test for those, but there are nasty edge cases --- a radius that is _almost_ along an axis will end up with two `surface()` points which are very close to each other, and that'll give me weird rounding/precision problems.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the `surface()` points and, if they are close enough to cause problems, carry out the more expensive (but accurate) calculation; otherwise, use the cheap/easy calculation.